# Smooth scrolling to anchor on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, smooth-scrolling

Call me stupid, but I don't see it. 
I have made a Joomla page with links to sections in the same page. very basic: `<a href="#sed">` and then `<p id="sed">`. I include jQuery like this:

```
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It is part of Joomla 3.

I am using this script from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/), which I have put in the  of the page:

```
    <script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I've fiddled with the [CSS Tricks sample page](https://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/) (copy/pasted it to my own HTML editor and changed a bit of the code) and yes, it works, but I can't get it to work in my own page. The page just jumps to the anchor but doesn't scroll smoothly.

Mind you: I hardly know anything of JavaScript or jQuery, so bear with me... to a jQuery specialist this must be a piece of cake....

Here is the test page I have made: [http://test.tomhiemstra.nl](http://test.tomhiemstra.nl/index.php).

Any help appreciated.

Cheers,

Thom

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with jQuery on your page, trying to select any element returns null. For example simply inserting `$('a')` in the console

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out what's causing this, but on your page the `$` isn't getting recognized. Replace all the `$` in your script to `jQuery` and it works.

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = jQuery(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        jQuery('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Alternatively, it's probably a better idea to wrap your function in one that will map the `$` to `jQuery`.

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hey Talya S., 
Many Thanks. I would never have worked this out myself. I changed the $ to jQuery and it worked. After that I added the code you suggested to the script I had found with the $ and it worked as well. I'll post underneath what ultimately works on the site. 

Question for you though: how did you discover what was wrong? Was that with the Google Chrome Console?

Comment: Yes, with the Chrome console (though other browsers have their own). I actually pasted the other answerer's script into there and got an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null(…)", so I tried fiddling with different selectors, until I noticed even the simplest ones didn't work (like I showed in the comment about `$('a')`)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 var target = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);
 if(target) {
  $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('[name=' + target +']').offset().top
        }, 1000);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Talya S. above, this is what I have come up with. I hope I have done it right, with all the brackets and curly brackets etc.:

```
    <script>
   (function ($) {
$(function () {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Did I add too many brackets or too few?

What I still don't understand, though, is why the $ was not recognised as jQuery, which is one of the most basic things you learn in jQuery (yes, I had come that far :-P). If anyone can clarify that to me "like I'm a four year old".

Thanx again Talya S. and my apologies for misspelling :-)

Thom

Comment: It's Talya not Tanya ;)   I'm not sure this is really how things are done here, if my answer solved things for you you just accept it, there's no need to post another one of your own. You can suggest edits to it in the comments if you feel it's incomplete, and ask questions of course. I'm also not sure what you pasted here, why it the script appearing twice

Comment: Also if there are things you still don't understand (like why $ is not recognized on your page) you could create a new question, or edit this one. A new answer really isn't the place.

Comment: You were so right, @Talya S, I was repeating the script. I thought the solution you gave was the wrap you mentioned, but you added the wrap to my script. I wasn't looking :-)